# How to split dynamic string and then apply pivot operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to perform split operation on a dynamic string like this,

```
'John Smith, US, 1001'
```

It seems simple at first but this string might be dynamic in nature, which means sometimes it can have more comma-separated values.

For example:

```
'Conrad Smith, UK, 1005, Permanent, 2021'
```

How can I split this dynamic string and perform pivot where I don't have specific number of values to make columns.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to use a dynamic query for dynamic string:

[image]

You store the split data in cols variable then use the cols for pivot

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
declare @strSql nvarchar(max)

set @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(value) 
        from string_split(@split_data,',')
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
set @strSql = 'SELECT '+ @cols +' from 
        (
            select LeaveTypeNo,MaxBalance from table1 p
            INNER  join table2 tei on p.Id = tei.Id                 
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(MaxBalance)
            for LeaveTypeNo in ('+ @cols +')
        ) p'
   EXEC (@strSql)
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'll need a dynamic sql as number of columns is not known. Case when there exists a limit of the number, say no more then 7 columns you can use a static version

```
select * into tbl 
from (
  values
    (1,'Conrad Smith, UK, 1005, Permanent, 2021')
) t(id, s);

select *
from tbl
cross apply (
  select [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
  from (
    select value, row_number() over(order by (select 1))  rn
    from string_split(s, ',')
  ) t
  pivot (max(value) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) p 
) t
```

Note `string_split` does not guarantee the order of tokens. I guess it is not a problem here, otherwise use a custom splitter.

Comment: `order by (select 1)` would make more sense as it makes it clearer that there is no ordering here

Comment: @Charlieface,   I see no difference as `s` is const in the context of the `order by` as well.

Comment: As I said, it makes it clearer, I didn't say it would make any difference operationally (likely not as you say)

Comment: @Charlieface,  the only advantage I see , it makes the query a bit easy to edit if a real column is not named `s`. Ok

Comment: It is not for Dynamic data